# How to handle too much Activites in Android?

Tags: android, video, android-activity, android-videoview

I am using VideoView to play videos in my app, therefore I need to create lots of Activities for each videos. My question is, is there anyway to handle this? Because I have created 100+ Activities so far.  I don't want my app to become too big because of too much Activities.

Comment: why you are creating activity for each video. just pass the link and used one videoview in activity and navigate videos "Next"/"Previous".

Comment: Do you have any tutorial for that?

Comment: Leon, no offense, but based on this question, it's self evident that you're not ready to write commercial grade software. You're not doing anyone any favors by releasing yet another semi-functional, terribly implemented, bug ridden app into the Android market. Please consider taking the time necessary to learn how to architect properly in Android and Java.  Given what you've described your app sounds like it should be 2 or 3 activities at most (1 is probably enough, if you lay it out properly).

Comment: Dr.Dredel, no offense, but you can't even find a solution for this yourself, yet you are telling me that "2 or 3 activities at most (1 is probably enough, if you lay it out properly)" That's why I am asking so that I can learn.

Comment: Plus, I haven't even published any app, I am just learning

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Leon you can use view flipper

this might help you

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android9TabWidgetFlipper.html#SlidingDrawer

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/29/android-switching-screens-by-dragging-over-the-touch-screen/

Comment: he would have a difficult time with his 100+ activities in a view flipper. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, quite honestly, most developers have to do the juggling act between functionality and low memory footprint. The best possible implementation is done keeping in mind various Activity States. Read up about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

That is the best you can do from your side. Android will always "kill" activities running in the background when resources are required for other active apps.

Comment: So you're saying that it can't be helped?

Comment: Not at all. Managing the Activity States properly usually gets it done.

Comment: What do you mean by "Managing the Activity States"?

Comment: Did you read the page from that link? You will find that covered under the topic heading: "Activity Lifecycle"

Comment: It might help to "kill" the activities but it won't help to make my app smaller in term of size which is my main problem here, you are kinda out of topic

Comment: You can't help the size of the application. With those many activities, it will be big anyway. The best you can do in that case is to optimize as many resources as possible. As an example, I would use XML to create a custom button instead of buttons using images.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to navigate next/previous video in a single activity. like playlist.

```
public class Test11Activity extends Activity {
private int currentVideo=0;
ArrayList<String> httpLinkArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
 VideoView videoView;
 Button n_button;
 Button p_button;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    httpLinkArrayList.add("http://abb.mp4");
    httpLinkArrayList.add("http://abb1.mp4");
    httpLinkArrayList.add("http://abb2.mp4");
    httpLinkArrayList.add("http://abb3.mp4");
    httpLinkArrayList.add("http://abb4.mp4");


    LinearLayout mainlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
```

mainlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout n_p_layout = new LinearLayout(this);

```
    n_button = new Button(this);
    n_button.setText("Next");
    n_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            if(currentVideo<httpLinkArrayList.size()){
                currentVideo++;
                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLinkArrayList.get(currentVideo)));
                videoView.start();
            }
        }
    });
    p_button = new Button(this);
    p_button.setText("Previous");
    p_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            if(currentVideo>0){
                currentVideo--;
                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLinkArrayList.get(currentVideo)));
                videoView.start();
            }
        }
    });
    n_p_layout.addView(n_button);
    n_p_layout.addView(p_button);        

    videoView = new VideoView(this);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLinkArrayList.get(currentVideo)));
    videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            if(currentVideo<httpLinkArrayList.size()){
                                    currentVideo++;
                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLinkArrayList.get(currentVideo)));
                videoView.start();
            }
        }
    });

    mainlayout.addView(n_p_layout);
    mainlayout.addView(videoView);

    setContentView(mainlayout);
}
```

}

hope useful to you.:)

Comment: mainlayout is simple linearlayout. you can set its property as per your requirement.

Comment: How come it doesn't have controls?

Comment: check now edited code. just missing mainlayout orientation vertical.mainlayout contain next- previous control and videoview.